# How can I repair a broken offset toilet flange?

Tags: toilet, flange

I am replacing the tile floor so I pulled the toilet to find this flange with the broken left slot and missing right tab too.  Any ideas on how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The oval shape of this offset makes it nearly impossible to seal correctly. Since you're removing the tile, think about trying to remove the flange and installing a better designd one like the one shown below from Home Depot. Not sure what your sub floor is but trying to fix the broken in two places flange could mean trouble down the road. The old flange also slows down the flush flow due to the weird step design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the PVC of the body of the flange is not cracked, the anchoring ring can be repaired with a [stainless repair ring.](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Sioux-Chief-886-MR-Stainless-Steel-Repair-Ring?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=Shopping_tm&utm_campaign=Shopping_TM_New_users&gclid=CjwKCAjw3oqoBhAjEiwA_UaLto574m94S6hJV46NwGWQ4liu0QXHMWN9Dcr0njMse89ctf1DqBe3SxoC0-wQAvD_BwE)